# How to implement an OpenId Provider in .net Framework without OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm developing some small services that interact with a .net framework application. These services have UI components that require authentication and will be hosted separately, but we have a requirement to use the existing login page. I'm hoping to set up IdentityServer4 as an authorization authority, and set up the legacy application as a OIDC provider.

The problem is that I have yet to find any information on how to do that in .net framework. I can't convert the legacy application to use .net core or owin hosting, which rules out identityserver3/4 as providers. DotNetOpenAuth is not certified as a provider and does not appear to provide a standard openid interface.

What libraries or patterns can I use to solve this problem?

EDIT: after some review, what I'm mostly looking for is a middleware that would let me convert a webforms authentication to an OIDC identity.

Comment: OpenId Provider should be isolated web app, so in that case you can use the ASP.NET Core with OWIN, no need to put it inside your legacy app

Answer (score 1):

Well.. you can start by reading http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html..

I faced the same problem a month back..

There are probably 4-6 specification documents that are dependent on this. you would have to read those as well (there is no shortcut) and you might want to start by making sequence diagrams on the get and post requests..

Amongst all this , read and implement a small jwt project which will help clear out your conception on how bearer tokens are used ( this involves how to create and validate bearer tokens)

Once you know jwt and have the sequence diagrams with you.. you can make improvisations and add more parameters..OpenId would seem relatively simpler

Also, do not forget to test your application with a third party client like postman or fiddler.

Hope this helps! All the best.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about rolling my own authorization flow. Ideally, I'd like to use something like identityserver to reduce the risk of me building a hole into my implementation. In your research, did you find no 3rd party library to help?